# Checkout process complete without ajax

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout

i have question if is possible make complete checkout process without ajax (in one action of controller)

currently i have some this code:

```
try {
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    // Create customer
    $customer = $this->prepareCustomer($data);
    // Create customer address from form
    $address = $this->prepareCustomerAddress($data,$customer);
    // Add product i want to car
    $cart = $this->prepareCart($data['package']);

    // Checkout start
    $this->_getOnepage()->saveBilling($address->getData(), $address->getId());
    $this->_getOnepage()->saveShipping($address->getData(), $address->getId());
    $this->_getOnepage()->saveShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
    $this->_getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
    $this->_getOnepage()->savePayment(array('method'=>$data['payment']['method']));         
    $order = $this->_getOnepage()->saveOrder();

    $order_id = $this->_getOnepage()->getLastOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);

    if($customer) {               
        $order->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
        $order->setCustomerIsGuest(false);
        $order->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId());
        $order->save();
    }
    $redirectUrl = $this->_getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getRedirectUrl();
    if($redirectUrl) {
        $redirect = $redirectUrl;
    } else {
        $redirect = Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage/success');
    }
    $this->_redirectUrl($redirect);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

My problem is: the code works, but after completion the order have 0 in price and items in order too (price: 0)

I cannot see where is problem.
The product i want is Virtual if its matter

Also if there are other methods (without external modules, or external module as reference can be answered)

Thanks

**EDIT:**

code for add to cart

```
public function prepareCart($sku) {
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    $cart->truncate();
    $cart->save();
    $cart->getItems()->clear()->save();
    $cart->init();

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

    $productId = $product->getIdBySku($sku);
    if ($productId) {
        $product->load($productId);
    }
    $cartParams = array(
        'qty'=>1
    );
    if ($product->getOptions()) {
        $ts = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp();
        foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
            if ($o->getDefaultTitle() == 'Date From') {
                $cartParams['options'][$o->getId()] = array(
                    'day' => intval(date('d',$ts)),
                    'month' => intval(date('m',$ts)),
                    'year' => intval(date('Y',$ts))
                );
            } elseif ($o->getDefaultTitle() == 'Date To') {
                $cartParams['options'][$o->getId()] = array(
                    'day' => intval(date('d',$ts)),
                    'month' => intval(date('m',$ts)),
                    'year' => intval(date('Y',$ts)+1)
                );
            }
        }
    }
    $cart->addProduct($product,$cartParams);
    $cart->save();
    return $cart;
}
```

Comment: check inchoo blog http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/

Comment: thanks, but i seen it already, i must create order as frontend (not backend as inchoo) and also redirect to payment gate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this, but not complete.

I send the request for order from frontend, so i managed customer, address and cart creation in one ajax request and return redirect to action which make checkout.

So after adding products to cart MUST be redirect otherwise checkout will not work and the code above is working.

thanks all for replies

Answer (score 1):

When you add the product try with this code snippet.

```
// Get product collection.
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                                                ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 'some_sku')
                                                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                                ->getFirstItem();

    // Load the product.
    $product->load($product->getId());

    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');

    // Clear the cart before customer adds any items.
    $cart->truncate();
    $cart->save();
    $cart->getItems()->clear()->save();
    try {
        // Add product to the cart.
        $cart->addProduct($product);
        $cart->save();
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
    unset($product);
```

Comment: thanks, i edited question with my addtocart.. this working well and is similar to yours, and i have also custom options in product

Comment: So did you manage to figured out the issue?

Comment: not now, finding, but without success